# making c# accurtate as posible (maybe with hacs)?

Tags: c#, usb, timing

From what I know it is rather known that c# can not be accurate when timing is critical. I certainly can understand that but was hoping there were known game hacks to help my issue.

tech:

I'm using an API for USB that sends data over a control transfer. In the API I get an event when an interrupt transfer occurs (one every 8 ms). I then simply fire off my control transfer at that exact time. What I have noticed, however not often, is that it takes more then 8ms to fire. Most of the time it does so in a timely matter (< 1ms after the interrupt event). The issue is that control transfers can not happen at the same time of an interrupt transfer so the control transfer must be done with in 5ms of the interrupt transfer so that it is complete and the interrupt transfer can take place.

So usb stuff aside my issue is getting an event to fire < 5ms after another event. I'm hoping there is a solution for this as gaming would also suffer form this sort of thing. For example some games can be put in a high priority mode. I wonder if that can be done in code? I may also try a profiler to back up my suspicions, it may be something I can turn off.

For those that want to journey down the technical road, the api is https://github.com/signal11/hidapi

If maybe someone has a trick or idea that may work, here are some of the considerations in my case.

1) usb interrupt polls happen ever 8 ms and are only a few hundred us long

2) control transfer should happen once every 8-32 ms (fast the better)

3) this control transfer can take up to 5 ms to complete

4) Skipping oscillations is ok for the controller transfer

5) this is usb 1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not even a C# problem, you are in a multi tasking non-realtime OS, so you don't know when your program is going to be active, the OS can give priority to other tasks.

Said that, you can raise the priority of the program thread, but I doubt it will solve anything:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
```

When such restrictive timmings must be met then you must work at kernel level, per example as a driver.

Comment: Funny you mention this. I was trying to determine the event timing and when looking in to the thread class I saw there was no interval. Deeper dinging came to this priority flag. So far no more issue, I hope that does it.

Comment: I have to say this did the trick, even if it does not fix the problem 24/7, 30 minutes is more than acceptable in my case.

Comment: Well, glad it solved your problem, but beware not having other apps with high priority, when you use your program try to have the less possible apps and services running.